# How to make gnome-screenshot select area to grab after a specified delay

Tags: gnome-screenshot

When I need to take a screenshot using gnome-screenshot, it is disabling the delay when I use "Select area to grab".

[image]

Is there any way to fix this defect?  Is it a defect or is it by design, and if so, why?

Comment: Grab the whole sceen, and then save and crop the image afterward, as a workaround?

Comment: I think "select area"+"delay" is not a very reliable way to "*take screenshots of some temporary popup windows*" as most of the time you are unsure where exactly the window will pop up and how big it would be.

Comment: Trying both via the terminal gives `Conflicting options: --area and --delay should not be used at the same time.` You'll need to contact the developers for the reason. I can't think of one.

Comment: `Spectacle`, the screenshot tool in Kubuntu 16.04 allows you to combine the "area to grab" option *and* a delay. Thanks for asking the question and making me look at things more closely.

Comment: This [GNOME bug 740089](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=740089) seems to be related. They disabled it without technical reason.

Comment: @N0rbert Spot on. I see your comment added to that GNOME bug. So Thanks for calling my attention to it.

Comment: @pomsky I agree. See [my non-answer using my screenshot.sh](https://askubuntu.com/a/1009381/340383) for my workaround that is similar to N0rbert's workaround. It is a non-answer because it requires another trip through Gimp-Land.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- It seems that GNOME developers removed this functionality from `gnome-screenshot` - it does not work on 14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS, 17.10 and 18.04 LTS) - I reported:

  1. [bug 1751161 to launchpad about disabled "Grab after a delay of..." in

     `gnome-screenshot -i`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-screenshot/+bug/1751161);
  2. [bug 1751157 to launchpad about option conflict in

     `gnome-screeshot --area --delay 10`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screenshot/+bug/1751157).
- On 16.04 LTS you can use `mate-screenshot` - it has delay in GUI (launched by `mate-screenshot -i -a`) and in terminal:

  ```
  mate-screenshot --area --delay 10
  ```

  but it is really ignored.

  In 16.04 LTS, 17.10 and 18.04 LTS delay is disabled when mate-screenshot ran interactively (`mate-screenshot -i`) - reported [bug 1751245 to launchpad about this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mate-utils/+bug/1751245).

  In 17.10 and 18.04 LTS it works only from terminal - so I reported [bug 1751141 to launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mate-utils/+bug/1751141).
- If you do not want to make screencast you can use the following:

  1. Open terminal and type `sleep 10 && gnome-screenshot --clipboard` here and click <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
  2. Open GIMP, paste image into it;
  3. Crop image in GIMP;
  4. Export image from GIMP to `.png`.
- You can use KDE Spectacle as *DK Bose* suggested:

  1. Install it with `sudo apt-get install kde-spectacle`;
  2. Launch it from terminal with `spectacle` or from menu launcher.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If it were allowed possible, I would click the up-button 5000 times. You have gone *well* above the call of duty here!

Comment: The workaround involving `sleep 10 ... ` seems the most viable/attractive until GNOME fixes the defect.

Comment: However, the [bug 1751157 to launchpad about option conflict in gnome-screenshot --area --delay 10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screenshot/+bug/1751157) you graciously filed shows `status: Confirmed → Invalid` which is confusing to me. Did they mark your bug as being invalid, which means it will be ignored? Clicking around the web site blocks me from quickly/easily understanding what "Invalid" actually means (blocked by login).

Comment: @bgoodr They marked it as duplicate of https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=740089 . I updated launchpad bug. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Use another app

A work around is to use a screen recorder:

[image: screen recorder.gif]

This was made with the package called [Peek](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/peek-desktop-gif-screen-recorder-linux)

After making your `.gif` file you can edit it to convert a single frame into a `.png` or `.jpg` image file.

Comment: Thanks. That is one of possibly many viable workarounds to https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=740089 . However, it has roughly the equivalent "finger burden" of the other alternatives mentioned so far.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a non-answer so that I can reference it elsewhere:

This script below is my workaround to misbehaved windows that do a "root X window grab". I can call it using:

```
screenshot.sh -d 5 -root
```

and it will allow me 5 seconds to fiddle with the misbehaving X window that pops up some dynamic (transient?) window and takes a full root window screenshot.

This is a non-answer to this question, because it has extra "finger burden" to crop the resulting image file down to the area of the dynamic popup using a tool such as Gimp. I need a single-shot turn-key solution that does not require me to do the same editing operation repeatedly during my workday.

This script depends upon `xwd` which is provided in (all?) X11 toolkits and also `convert` provided by (well at least on my Ubuntu 17.10 desktop install) the `graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat` package:

```
#!/bin/bash
# -*-mode: Shell-script; indent-tabs-mode: nil; -*-

# This seems to hang on me on the RHEL6 desktop:
#
#   gnome-screenshot --window --delay=3
#
# So use xwd + convert instead:

usage () {
  echo "USAGE: $0 [ -d DURATION ] [ -root ]"
}

DURATION="3"
TARGET=""
while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
  if [ "$1" = "-d" ]
  then
    DURATION="$2"
    shift
  elif [ "$1" = "-root" ]
  then
    TARGET="root"
  elif [ "$1" = "-h" ]
  then
    usage
    exit 0
  else
    echo "ERROR: Unrecognized option $1"
    exit 1
  fi
  shift
done

xwdOptions=""
if [ "$TARGET" = "root" ]
then
  echo "Sleeping for $DURATION seconds so that you can reposition windows for taking screenshot of root window ..."
  xwdOptions="-root"
else
  echo "Sleeping for $DURATION seconds so that you can raise the appropriate window ..."
fi
sleep $DURATION

timestamp="$(date +%Y-%m-%d.%H-%M-%S.%Z)"
screenshot_path="$HOME/screenshot.$timestamp.png"

# Per https://askubuntu.com/questions/962848/imagemagick-identify-fails-to-identify-xwd-images#comment1542670_962848 :
xwd $xwdOptions | convert xwd:- $screenshot_path

echo
echo "SCREENSHOT:       $screenshot_path"
echo
#echo 'Alternatively, use the ImageMagick "import the_output.png" command to select a region'
```

Answer (score 1):

This was finally fixed in the git version, thanks to Philipp Wolfer:
[Allow taking area screenshots with delay (164e779a) · Commits · Philipp Wolfer / gnome-screenshot · GitLab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/phw/gnome-screenshot/-/commit/164e779ac8a7b94f2bbbbe2c4d0d6b1215b9f341).

> Remove the workaround that disables the timeout option

The [Launchpad issue is also updated](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screenshot/+bug/1751157/comments/2)

I'm not sure which version of GNOME or Ubuntu it will appear in.

Thanks to everyone who helped along the way to get this fixed.